# Failed in Fetching updates from google

Tags: android-sdk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on bash on ubuntu on windows. i installed kivy, buildozer, cython and jdk all the necessary modules required to build apk from buildozer.
This is how i am making apk

```
buildozer init
```

and then after editing buildozer.spec file

```
buildozer android debug
```

now it install ANT, SDK and NDK but after installing these buildozer **fatch data from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
and after sometime gives error that last command fail unable to fatch data.**

i see many answers related to it and they say it is because of protocol. instead of using https it should have to use http. but i dont know how to do that cause buildozer download no_ui sdk.

please anyone can solve it...

Comment: `I am working on bash on ubuntu on windows`. I don't understand why don't you try VM or dual-boot or working exact on Windows

Comment: i'm working on vm but still bash is new that's why i try to shift my project to bash on ubuntu. All errors are resolved now